# GPO account lockout policy not applying but other policies in GPO do

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

I have a GPO that defines password policies and a logout policy after a set amount of invalid attempts:

[image]

I have ensured that this GPO is applied at domain level.

Password policies apply fine and function correctly. How come Account Lockout Policy does not?

Powershell Result:

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other Account Lockout Policies applied? Does the Policy apply to your Domain Controllers?

Comment: Silly question, but how did you know it's not applying correctly? your answer might give us a clue on how to proceed.

Comment: I know it's not applying correctly because I've tested it by deliberately entering incorrect password 4+ times in a row. @NoorKhaldi

Comment: @Dan There are no other lockout policies applied. It does not apply to domain controllers.

Comment: @AugustWilliams I believe it needs to apply to the DC's

Answer (score 1):

Based on your answer in the comments:

> Failed password attempts on workstations or member servers that have
>   been locked by using CTRL+ALT+DELETE or password-protected screen
>   savers do not count as failed sign-in attempts unless **Interactive
>   logon: Require Domain Controller authentication to unlock
>   workstation** is set to **Enabled**. **If Interactive logon: Require
>   Domain Controller authentication to unlock workstation** is enabled,
>   repeated failed password attempts to unlock the workstation will count
>   against the account lockout threshold.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994574(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: I have tried this but no change.

Comment: Instead of trying to use a wrong password 4 times, let's try to get the applied password policy using PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-addefaultdomainpasswordpolicy?view=win10-ps will help you see what's happening, paste your findings here and lets compare against the GPO.

Comment: I have used PowerShell and it turns out not all elements match the GPO, including the lockout threshold. See question for a screenshot of the output.

Comment: Interesting, then try to set the elements again using PowerShell: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-addefaultdomainpasswordpolicy?view=win10-ps

Comment: I have managed to accomplish the same outcome with Active Directory Administrative Centre. What are the differences between password policies with a GPO and DSAC? Because both have the same level of customisation. I will try the GPO with powershell too.

Answer (score 1):

You're mistaken.  This policy does NOT have to be set for lockout to work on locked workstations.  This ONLY applies:  When cached credentials are used, any CHANGES THAT HAVE **RECENTLY BEEN MADE** made to the account (such as user rights assignments, account lockout, or the account being disabled) are not considered or applied after this authentication process.

I have tested this and workstations that are simply locked will get locked out according to group policy.